# Select * into #table from execute(@query)

Tags: database, t-sql, azure-sql-database, select-into

I have created a dynamic query which returns the number of columns from table as:

```
set @query = 'select '+@cols+' from [Sample] '
```

Now I want to fill a temporary table by executing this query, When I try this

```
select * into #table from execute(@query).
```

I get following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'execute'

And

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

However running this command returns the result accurately : `execute(@query)`

**Note: I have tried OPENROWSET which is not supported in sql-azure.**

Please help if there is any other work around.

Comment: The syntax would be `insert #table execute(@query)` however this requires `#table` to already exist, which means you must know the correct column definitions inline in order to create it, which presumably is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use FQ table name and not #temptable:

```
 IF object_id('tempdb..temptable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].[temptable] 
 DECLARE @query varchar(4000)
 SET @query = 'select '+ @cols +' into [tempdb].[dbo].[temptable] from [Sample]'

 EXECUTE (@query)

 SELECT * from [tempdb].[dbo].[temptable]
```

Please see the result in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3318/9)

Comment: Number of columns will be dynamic, for that reason I cannot create table before insert.